# Explanation of $\ker (\bar{m}-\bar{id})^2 \cap \{x_0=1\}$

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry, isometry

Let $m$ be an isometry **on $\mathbb{R}^2$** which is a composition of a reflection and a translation.

The way to find the axis of the isomtry is by solving:

$$\ker (\bar{m}-\bar{id})^2 \cap \{x_0=1\}$$

Could someone please briefly explain the reason for that equation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this in $\mathbb R^2$, $\mathbb R^3$, or $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @StevenGregory I'm sorry, you're right, I forgot to mention it. It's $\mathbb{R}^2$.